# PrimaryKey and AutoIncrement

Tags: c#, sqlite

In the following code, what do `PrimaryKey` and `AutoIncrement` mean?

```
using SQLite;

namespace Todo
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public bool Done { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tutorial : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm

Comment: @SushiHangover AUTOINCREMENT is the most misunderstood thing about sqlite. https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html for what it really does (The first example in that "tutorial"'s syntax section will even raise an error!)

Comment: @Shawn Not sure what "version" of SQLite you are using, but those SQL examples work fine....

Comment: @SushiHangover `column1 INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT` causes a syntax error, just like the documentation says it will. Has to be a `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column. That article makes it sound like it can be used with any INTEGER column, which simply isn't true. (Nor is it needed to make an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrementing. It's really a poorly named keyword)

Comment: @Shawn That is a `syntax` example via the SQL language structure, use the actual SQLite SQL statement(s) given as examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AUTOINCREMENT** is a complimentary keyword that can only be used in one situation and that is for a PRIMARY KEY that is has a column type specifically of INTEGER (case dependant).

**If not used in this situation then a syntax error will occur.**

A **PRIMARY KEY** is the main (as far as the user is concerned) index.

If `column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is coded then that column, then that column becomes an alias of the **rowid** column.

- The **rowid** column (unless the table is defined with the WITHOUT ROWID keyword) is a column that is normnally hidden (e.g. SELECT * does not return the **rowid**). The **rowid** is the real primary index, it's value is an integer (64 bit signed integer) initially 1, it is always unique and generally increases and frequently by 1). It uniqiuely identifies a row.

If an alias of the **rowid** column is used then if no value is supplied when inserting a row it will be an automatically generated value as per the **rowid** if a value is supplied then the row will be inserted with that value. Noting that the value must be an integer and that it must be unique.

Now if the **rowid**'s (including an alias thereof) highest value is greater than 9223372036854775807 then the normal algorithm, if no value has been supplied, will try to use a free lower value.

If **AUTOINCREMENT** is coded a lower value will not be used, instead an SQLITE_FULL exception will arise.

Thus **AUTOINCREMENT** compliments INTEGER PRIMARY KEY to impose the restriction that the unique value must always increase. It does this at some expense as it uses a table called **sqlite_sequence** to store the highest allocated **rowid** (or alias thereof).

As such consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aifill;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS noaifill;
CREATE TABLE noaifill (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE aifill (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);

INSERT INTO aifill VALUES (null),(null),(null),(null);
INSERT INTO noaifill VALUES (null),(null),(null),(null);
SELECT * FROM aifill JOIN noaifill ON aifill.ID = noaifill.ID;

INSERT INTO aifill VALUES(9223372036854775807);
INSERT INTO noaifill VALUES(9223372036854775807);
SELECT * FROM aifill JOIN noaifill ON aifill.ID = noaifill.ID;

INSERT INTO noaifill VALUES(null);
SELECT * FROM noaifill;

INSERT INTO aifill VALUES(null); -- <<<<<<<<<< FAILS
SELECT * FROM aifill JOIN noaifill ON aifill.ID = noaifill.ID;
```

Then the results are :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

The messages :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aifill
> OK
> Time: 0.351s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS noaifill
> OK
> Time: 0.312s


CREATE TABLE noaifill (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)
> OK
> Time: 0.266s


CREATE TABLE aifill (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)
> OK
> Time: 0.299s


INSERT INTO aifill VALUES (null),(null),(null),(null)
> Affected rows: 4
> Time: 0.262s


INSERT INTO noaifill VALUES (null),(null),(null),(null)
> Affected rows: 4
> Time: 0.273s


SELECT * FROM aifill JOIN noaifill ON aifill.ID = noaifill.ID
> OK
> Time: 0s


INSERT INTO aifill VALUES(9223372036854775807)
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.366s


INSERT INTO noaifill VALUES(9223372036854775807)
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.291s


SELECT * FROM aifill JOIN noaifill ON aifill.ID = noaifill.ID
> OK
> Time: 0s


INSERT INTO noaifill VALUES(null)
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.259s


SELECT * FROM noaifill
> OK
> Time: 0s


INSERT INTO aifill VALUES(null)
> database or disk is full
> Time: 0s
```

Answer (score 0):

Those attributes are from `SQLite.NET`

- `[PrimaryKey]` – This attribute can be applied to an integer property to force it to be the underlying table's primary key. Composite primary keys are not supported.
- `[AutoIncrement]` – This attribute will cause an integer property's value to be auto-increment for each new object inserted into the database

[SQLite.NET](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/data-and-cloud-services/data-access/part-3-using-sqlite-orm/)

Comment: So are PrimaryKey and AutoIncrement applying to public int ID?